# Bin bash: Launch python file with given sh file arguments

Tags: python, bash

I have `relay2.sh` file which should launch a python file with given arguments. So I'm using domoticz smart home system, and my task is to launch the shell script from domoticz with - `script://relay2.sh 192.168.11.4 4196 1 1`, arguments are - IP, PORT, RELAY, RELAY_STATUS. What I'm doing is, starting a sh file and passing arguments from domoticz to sh file. After that I'm trying to start a python file with given arguments from sh file. But it doesn't work. I really don't know how can I pass the arguments from sh to py file.

Here's my sh code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1 $2 $3 $4 --test_vars-- (working)"
#!/usr/bin/python3
update.py $1 $2 $3 $4
```

Comment: Does `python3 update.py $1 $2 $3 $4` without shebang line solve your problem?

Comment: @makr3la Hmm, well yes it works, but if I launch it from domoticz with the script:// regex which I showed it doesn't, and I do get a Error `Error executing script command (/home/interkodas/domoticz/scripts/relay2.sh). returned: 512`, and as I can see after some research, I need to do this - Every (Python) script must begin with:
`#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: You must decide wheter you script is a shell script (`#!/bin/bash`) or a python script (`#!/usr/bin/python`). It can't be both.

Comment: @SimonFink any ideas how to pass arguments to `#!/usr/bin/python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) wrong. Each file may only contain one shebang (e.g. `#!/bin/bash`) and tells the command line interface which executable to use, when executing the script.

As your script is meant to be a shell script, the shebang to use is `#!/bin/bash`.

In order to pass the arguments to your python script, you need to call `python3 update.py $1 $2 $3 $4`, assuming that python3 is on your `PATH` variable. You can check this with `echo $PATH` and/or `which python3`

If you want a pure python script to be executed from command line, you have to add the python shebang (`#!/usr/bin/python`) to your python file and process the arguments within that script. A good tutorial can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm).

Comment: Well, yes it answers my question. But do you know any ideas how then I can pass the arguments to `#!/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: You will need to modify your python script `update.py`. You can add the python shebang `#!/usr/bin/python` to the top of the file and process command line arguments within the file. Look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm) for a good explanation. Instead of the bash script you can then invoke the python script directly.

Comment: Thanks, I added `#!/usr/bin/python3` in the top of my python file and now it works:)